# Show JSON data in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

First I have proper JSON data in format:

```
{"data":[{"ID":1,"aktivnost":"prodaja","vrsta":"Kultura","artikl":"psenica","6":222,"jmere":"Kg","7":290,"porez":20,"dobavljac":"M. Milic","datum":"2014-04-24","datum_dospeca":"0000-00-00","8":288,"nacin_placanja":"gotovinsko","skladiste":"Novo skladiste","opis":"Prodaja robe bla bla bla"},{"ID":2,"aktivnost":"prodaja","vrsta":"kultura","artikl":"kukuruz","6":777,"jmere":"kom","7":8000,"porez":20,"dobavljac":"milence","datum":"2014-04-19","datum_dospeca":"0000-00-00","8":8000,"nacin_placanja":"gotovinsko","skladiste":"nn","opis":"opis"},{"ID":3,"aktivnost":"investicija","vrsta":"parcela","artikl":"Nad gred","6":1,"jmere":"kom","7":2300,"porez":20,"dobavljac":"Nebojsa B.","datum":"2014-04-04","datum_dospeca":"0000-00-00","8":1200,"nacin_placanja":"gotovinsko","skladiste":"","opis":"opis"}]}
```

I have HTML:

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsitive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Dospece</th>
                <th>Akt</th>
                <th>Vrsta</th>
                <th>Artikl</th>
                <th>Kolicina</th>
                <th>Iznos</th>
                <th>Placeno</th>
                <th>Nacin</th>
                <th>Kome</th>
                <th>Skl</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Dospece</th>
                <th>Akt</th>
                <th>Vrsta</th>
                <th>Artikl</th>
                <th>Kolicina</th>
                <th>Iznos</th>
                <th>Placeno</th>
                <th>Nacin</th>
                <th>Kome</th>
                <th>Skl</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

and I try to run dataTable with this Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawVisualization();

    });
function drawVisualization() {

                $('#example').dataTable({ 
                         "ajax": {
            "url": 'getfinansije.php',
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                if(!json.data){

            //$('#tmeh').hide();
            json.data = [];
        }
                return json.data;
            },
                    "error": function (data){
                console.log(data);
                    }
        },
                    paging: false,
                    //"dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                    "oLanguage": {
    "sInfo": 'Ukupno _END_ transakcija.',
    "sInfoEmpty": 'Nema zabelezenih transakcija',
    "sEmptyTable": "Nema transakcija, dodajte klikom na dugme 'Dodaj kupoprodaju'.",
},
                    "columns": [{
                            "data": "ID"
                        }, {
                            "data": "datum"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data": "datum_dospeca"
                        },{
                            "data": "aktivnost"
                        },

                        {
                            "data": "vrsta"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "artikl"
                        },

                        {
                            "data": "6"
                        },
                         {
                            "data": "7"
                        },{
                            "data": "8"
                        },
                         {
                            "data": "dobavljac"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "nacin_placanja"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "skladiste"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "jmere"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "porez"
                        },
                         {
                            "data": "opis"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "akcija"
                        }
                    ],
                     "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aasData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

        var columnas = [6, 7, 8]; //the columns you wish to add            
        for (var j in columnas) {
            var columnaActual = columnas[j];
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
                total = total + parseFloat(aasData[aiDisplay[i]][columnaActual]);
            }
            $($(nRow).children().get(columnaActual-1)).html(total);

        }
    }, 
                    "columnDefs": [
                            {
                        "targets": [0, 12, 13, 14],
                        "visible":false
                            },
                         {
                        "targets": 15,
                        "data": "akcija",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            // return data; 
                            return '<div style="float:right;"><button class="btn btn-info troskovnik" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update">Detalji...</button> <i  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" class="fa fa-times"></i></div>';
                        }
                            },
                              { 
                        "targets": 3,
                        "data": "aktivnost",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            if (data=='prodaja') {
                            return '<button class="btn btn-success">'+data+'</button>';
                            } else if (data=='kupovina'){
                                                        return '<button class="btn btn-warning" >'+data+'</button>';

                            } else {
                                                        return '<button class="btn btn-info" >'+data+'</button>';

                            }

                            }
                              }


    ]
                });


            }
```

but I don't see datatable, so dataTable is there but values from JSON I don't see. I just see blank table without data.

Also In console log there is 2 errors:

> dataTables.keyTable.js:1169 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'KeyTable' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>   undefinedjquery.dataTables.min.js:58

Also please see what I get when I try to destroy table - I get the same error:

[image]

I get just this two error but I don't know what then means. I tried to solve this problem, please help me with this!

Comment: never even seen a file `dataTables.keyTable.js` when I've used datatables. Suggest you use non minified version to find out where in code problems occur and set brekapoints to try to locate problem

Comment: I remove keyTable.js and now I have only this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined , problem on line 58 at file: jquery.dataTables.min.js:58

Comment: Also I see that my code: $('#example').dataTable({ 
                         "ajax": {
            "url": 'getFin.php', ... etc. NEVER CALL getFin.php - I see that this file never called from console log

Comment: hard to debug using minified version, use development version so you can look at the line that throws error. Then try to look at your code to see what might use that line. Setting breakpoints would help also and inspect values in stack

Comment: I thin that is problem becouse I get this when I try to run js code: 304
Not Modified ... What 304 mean?